# Is there any way to change value of variable set by t-set in template odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I need to change value of a variable set by t-set in a template by inherit that template, change value of variable and add some fields based on condition of that variable but can't find how can I do that without overwrite whole codes of template

Example I want to change zip_city in below template:

```
 <template id="address" name="Address Management">
    <t t-call="website.layout">
       ........... 
       <t t-set='zip_city' t-value='country and [x for x in country.get_address_fields() if x in ["zip", "city"]] or ["city", "zip"]'/>
       <t t-if="'zip' in zip_city and zip_city.index('zip') &lt; zip_city.index('city')">
```

Comment: Inherit template and just replace field by jquery argument.

Comment: I need to replace a variable not a field so can't call it from jquery

Comment: Finally I resolved it by call t-set in xpath :
 `<xpath expr="//t[@t-set='zip_city']" position="replace">`

Answer (score 1):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<templates id="template">

    <t t-name="name of your template" t-extend="name of parent template">
        <t t-jquery="field name" t-operation="replace">
            // customization
        </t>
    </t>

</templates>
```

Try by this way..